# Adding custom header based on the ngx.re.match()

Tags: regex, nginx, lua

I'm trying to add custom header based on the `uri` value, in this case for all the `pdf` files:

```
  header_filter_by_lua_block {
    local m, err = ngx.re.match(ngx.var.uri, "%.pdf$", "io")
    if m then
      ngx.log(ngx.ERR, "found match: ", m[0])
      ngx.header["X-Custom-Header"] = "ZZzz"
    end
  }
```

I'm using [lua-nginx-module](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module) in this task, therefore I expected that standard `lua` [regex syntax](https://www.lua.org/pil/20.2.html) should apply, thus `%.` should match `.` (dot), however it doesn't seem to work. What's the problem?

If I change regex from `%.pdf$` to `.pdf$` then it does work, but obviously it matches not just `blabla.pdf` but also `blablapdf`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

lua-nginx-module uses PCRE (Perl compatible regular expression), so `\` should be used instead of `%` to escape special characters. Backslash is also Lua string escape symbol, so *double escape* is needed:

```
ngx.re.match(ngx.var.uri, "\\.pdf$", "io")
```

Alternatively, you can use bracket string literals instead of quotes to avoid double escape:

```
ngx.re.match(ngx.var.uri, [[\.pdf$]], "io")
```